# How can a set be a subset of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Take the measure space $(X,\mathcal A)$, and a set $S\subset X$. What does $S\subset \mathcal A$ actually mean?

$A\subset B$ if every element of $A$ is also in $B$. But elements of $\mathcal A$ are sets of elements from $X$, whereas elements of $S$ are the elements themselves. Thus I don't understand what is the meanig of $S\subset \mathcal A$

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: it's perfectly fine if $S$ is a collection of subsets of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: To expound upon Batman's anwer, $S\subseteq X$ means $S$ is some collection of points in $X$; however $S\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ means that $S$ is a collection of *sets* in $\mathcal{A}$. These two are completely distinct ideas (since $\mathcal{A}$ is made up of subsets of $X$).

Comment: Just to clarify, if I wrote $S\subset 2^X$, it would be fine, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someones probably made a typo -- They probably meant $S \in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Good. Everything alright with the world and the impostor syndrome is quiet again. Thanks!